# JS moved to webpack breaks in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I am gradually switching from Asset pipeline to webpack for JS assets and got an error in my console:

> ReferenceError: open_select is not defined
>       at HTMLParagraphElement.onclick

The bit of code that creates the problem is coming from an HTML element in the view that has not been changed at all :

```
<span onclick="open_select(this)" class="icon_select_mate" >
```

The only thing I did is move the JS that is tied to this html from app/assets/javascript to app/javascript. 
Then adding it to the application.js pack.

When I check the application.js pack I can see the JS that has been migrated to webpack.

Then not sure what the problem is .